# When I run "Docker ps" I can't see some container. What wrong with me?

Tags: docker, containers

I am testing docker with official doc. just following official doc.
I am using official code

https://github.com/docker/getting-started/tree/master/app

and then this Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

and then build command

```
docker build -t getting-started .
```

and then run command

```
docker run -dp 3000:3000 getting-started
```

It's perfect. but I just want to modified a little code more simple.
like this. This is nodejs code.

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

and then Dockerfile like this

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

and then build and run same command.
I checked my running container with this command "docker ps".I couldn't see my container is running.

I ran "docker ps -a" command. I was able to see the container with no port mapping container. So I wasn't able to connect my container.

I added both of docker state.
I ran same command but firstcontainer don't have port mapping. What's wrong?

```
docker run -dp 80:3000 getting-started   -> this is official app
docker run -dp 3000:3000 firstcontainer  -> my simple app
docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS  PORTS
fea13c68893f   firstcontainer    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   10 seconds ago   Exited (1) 10 seconds ago  
2f552d1e9f55   getting-started   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago   Up 25 seconds  
 0.0.0.0:80->3000/tcp, :::80->3000/tcp
```

Comment: did you kill the first one before running the new one?

Comment: Exactly I did my sample code frist, It was not working well. So I followed official doc, again. Official doc was working well.

Comment: which OS are you using? did you make sure that the port isn't taken between two runs?

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 on AWS

Comment: `netstat -na | grep LISTEN` between those 2 runs, to ensure that port not in use

Comment: netstat -na | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: added docker status the question.
I ran your command 80 port is working well this is officical app. but 3000 port didn't assigned for container.

Comment: did you try to run without the `d` flag (not in background) to see the logs?

Comment: Wow I solved it. my index.js file location was wrong. I moved index.js file to src directory. Thank you so much. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the docker command in foreground to see the logs (without the `d` flag):

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 firstcontainer  -> my simple app
```

and see what's the error

Comment: You're my life saver.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EXPOSE` instruction is written after `CMD`. Change it to come before `CMD`. The `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` MUST be the last instruction in your `Dockerfile`. There is nothing to "run" in this image otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. 
I tried to change  CMD line but it's same and. docker official doc put EXPOSE the last line.